# I accidentally deleted crucial videos from my iPhone DCIM folder on my desktop

Tags: data-recovery, iphone, dcim

I copied the files onto my desktop and then accidentally clicked 'delete' on my keyboard. It deleted the selected videos. I then did ctrl+z which deleted the copied files that I placed on my desktop. Now I have no access to any of the files. Is there any way I can recover the files I deleted?

EDIT: I cannot use the programs/solutions stated in the possible duplicate question because it does not detect my iPhone as a drive.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I am on iOS 9.2

Comment: I mean on the desktop copmuter.

Comment: If you cannot mount the drive, then the files on the phone, cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better stop using the your iphone, this will prevent new files to be written to the device and hence increase chance of DCIM folder data recovery.

Some suggestion for you:

**If you deleting videos from iPhone Using a Mac**

This works in all versions of Mac OS X:

- Connect the iPhone to the computer via USB;
- Launch videos from the /Applications/ folder;
- Hit Command+A to Select All videos, then with all images selected
  click the red () button to delete all videos.
- Confirm deletion when asked and be prepared to wait.

**If you delete All Photos from iPhone Using Windows PC**

This should work in all versions of Windows:

- Connect the iPhone to the computer via USB;
- Open ‘My Computer’ and choose “Apple iPhone”;
- Open to folders “Internal Storage” and then open “DCIM”, contained
  within will be a folder containing all videos on the iPhone;
- From the folder containing the videos, select all, then delete
  Removing videos from the iPhone.

**Select a recovery suite.**

The software mentioned is [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm) and [Recuva for Windows](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download/standard), which are both free options.